# What is best way to implement multi-lingual / internationalization in Graph database?

Tags: graph, internationalization, gremlin, graph-databases, property-graph

What is best way to implement `multi-lingual / internationalization` in Graph database?

I am using `Gremlin-Neputune` Property graph database. I did not find any default implementation for multilingual

Let say, I have node `Role` with property `Employee`, How to maintain the same in different language?

Comment: Is the question about having a properties with strings in different languages? For example `name_en` and `name_de`

Comment: Yes. @KelvinLawrence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDF/SPARQL has multi lingual support built in which is handy - strings can be annotated as being in a specific language. Gremlin does not have such a concept. However you could do something like this:

```
g.addV('City').
  property('name_en', 'London').
  property('name_fr', 'Londres').
  property('name_ne', 'Londen')
```

Comment: How about using metaproperties for multi-lingual? Do you think this will work?

Answer (score 0):

Another option:- Having meta-properties to the default language property

```
g.addV('city').
  property('name', 'London', 'name_fr', 'Londres', 'name_ne', 'Londen')
```

Reference for MetaProperties: http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#metaprop

Comment: I did not suggest meta properties as not all graph databases support them.

Comment: Agree. AWS Neptune is not supporting MetaProperties.

Comment: Any suggestion on MultiProperties?

Comment: My hesitation on multi properties is that they are not K/V pairs so how will you know which language each string is in? I don't think you can depend on the order in the set for example. Unless you store them as something like "London@en" - sort of RDF style

Comment: Okay got it. thanks for your input & time.